How do I do the equivalent of SELECT COUNT type of query in SwiftData on related data?
I have a model which is similar to:
import Foundation
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

@Model
final class AccountTransaction {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    var transactionType: TransactionType = TransactionType.debit
    var amount: Decimal = 0
    var balance: Decimal = 0
    var pending: Date? = nil
    var cleared: Date? = nil
    var notes: String = ""
    var confirmationNumber: String = ""
    var recurringTransaction: RecurringTransaction? = nil
    var dueDate: Date? = nil
    var isTaxRelated: Bool = false
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \TransactionFile.transaction)
    var files: [TransactionFile]? = nil
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .noAction)
    var account: Account? = nil

    // The id of the account this belongs to. This is required because predicates don't allow you to filter on other models.
    var accountId: UUID
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .noAction)
    var transactionTags: [TransactionTag]? = nil
    var balancedOn: Date? = nil
    var createdOn: Date = Date()

    /// The amount of files associated with the transaction.
    var fileCount: Int {
        self.files?.count ?? 0
    }

    /// The background color indicating the status of the transaction.
    var backgroundColor: Color {
        switch self.transactionStatus {
        case .cleared:
            Color.clear
        case .pending:
            Color(.sRGB, red: 255/255, green: 150/255, blue: 25/255, opacity: 0.5)
        case .reserved:
            Color(.sRGB, red: 255/255, green: 25/255, blue: 25/255, opacity: 0.5)
        }
    }

    /// The inferred status of the transaction.
    var transactionStatus: TransactionStatus {
        if self.pending == nil && self.cleared == nil {
            return .reserved
        } else if self.pending != nil && self.cleared == nil {
            return .pending
        } else {
            return .cleared
        }
    }

    init(id: UUID = UUID(), account: Account, name: String = "", transactionType: TransactionType = .debit, amount: Decimal = 0, balance: Decimal = 0, pending: Date? = nil, cleared: Date? = nil, notes: String = "", confirmationNumber: String = "", recurringTransaction: RecurringTransaction? = nil, files: [TransactionFile]? = [], transactionTags: [TransactionTag]? = [], isTaxRelated: Bool = false, dueDate: Date? = nil, balancedOn: Date? = nil, createdOn: Date = Date()) {
        self.id = id
        self.account = account
        self.name = name
        self.transactionType = transactionType
        self.amount = amount
        self.balance = balance
        self.pending = pending
        self.cleared = cleared
        self.notes = notes
        self.confirmationNumber = confirmationNumber
        self.recurringTransaction = recurringTransaction
        self.dueDate = dueDate
        self.isTaxRelated = isTaxRelated
        self.files = files
        self.transactionTags = transactionTags
        self.balancedOn = balancedOn
        self.createdOn = createdOn

        self.accountId = account.id

        self.VerifySignage()
    }

    func VerifySignage() {
        switch self.transactionType {
        case .credit:
            self.amount = abs(self.amount)
        case .debit:
            self.amount = -abs(self.amount)
        }
    }

    func SaveTransaction(modelContext: ModelContext, transaction: AccountTransaction, name: String, amount: Decimal) {
        transaction.name = name

        try? modelContext.save()

        // perhaps we open with async stuff and return the transaction?
    }
}

And the relataionship I care about is:
import Foundation
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

@Model
final class TransactionFile {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    var filename: String = ""
    var notes: String = ""
    var createdOn: Date = Date()
    var url: URL? = nil
    var data: Data? = nil
    var isTaxRelated: Bool = false
    var fileType: FileType? = nil

    @Relationship(deleteRule: .noAction)
    var transaction: AccountTransaction?

    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String = "", filename: String = "", notes: String = "", createdOn: Date = Date(), url: URL? = nil, data: Data? = nil, fileType: FileType? = nil ,isTaxRelated: Bool = false, transaction: AccountTransaction? = nil) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.filename = filename
        self.notes = notes
        self.createdOn = createdOn
        self.url = url
        self.data = data
        self.transaction = transaction
        self.isTaxRelated = isTaxRelated
        self.fileType = fileType
    }
}

Clearly AccountTransaction.fileCount returns 0 unless I include those in the initial query - but that will also pull the binary data (which isn't in there yet but will be). All I care about is a count.
I plan on adding other similar types of counts in the future in other models.
I don't see a clear and simply way to do a simple count without actually pulling the data. It has me considering just doing everything with manual SQL queries but I'm sure I'm missing something painfully obvious.
An example of the way I'm currently doing my queries is this:
  private func performAccountTransactionFetch(currentPage: Int = 0) {
        let accountId: UUID = self.account.id

        // TODO: Remove this test UUID
        let testUUID = UUID(uuidString: "12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc")
        let predicate = #Predicate<AccountTransaction> { transaction in
            if transaction.accountId == accountId || transaction.accountId == testUUID! {
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }

        var fetchDescriptor = FetchDescriptor<AccountTransaction>(predicate: predicate)
        fetchDescriptor.fetchLimit = transactionsPerPage
        fetchDescriptor.fetchOffset = self.currentAccountTransactionPage * transactionsPerPage
        fetchDescriptor.sortBy = [.init(\.createdOn, order: .reverse)]

        guard !isLoading && hasMoreTransactions else { return }
        isLoading = true
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
                do {
                    let newTransactions = try modelContext.fetch(fetchDescriptor)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        accountTransactions.append(contentsOf: newTransactions)
                        isLoading = false
                    }
                } catch {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        print("Error fetching transactions: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        isLoading = false
                    }
                }
            }
    }

And I don't see an easy way to query how I want.
So... How do I do a simple count without doing unnecessary queries specifically in SwiftData?
If this were raw SQL I know exactly how I'd do it but I'm trying to stick with SwiftData as best I can because, ideally, I'd like for it to sync to the cloud in the future so it could work on my iPad, iPhone, and Mac without having to host a local (or hosted) service, ideally.

You use fetchCount(…) which works the same way as the fetch method but only returns the count of matching objects

Thanks, I'll try that first chance I get. Much appreciated!

Ok, so it seems fetchCount really is the only way to do this. I was really hoping I could do something cool like one can do in Linq with .Net.
So the end result is I have to pass in a modelContext and make a new function:
func getFileCount(modelContext: ModelContext) -> Int {
        let descriptor = FetchDescriptor<TransactionFile>(predicate: #Predicate { $0.transactionId == self.id })

        return (try? modelContext.fetchCount(descriptor)) ?? 0
    }

AND I also have to add transactionId to the TransactionFile model because for some reason you really can't do self.transaction.id. Seems like an ugly answer but it's the best SwiftData has to offer currently. I'll have to do some tests to see if it's worth doing it async of sync.

Yes you can use self.transaction.id but not inside the predicate so create a local variable, let id = self.transaction.id in the function and then use that in the predicate
